# How to use window.open in onclick inside each loop

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, each, window.open

I am trying to show page content inside PhoneGap app.
This works very fine:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com', '_self ', 'location=yes');">google.com</a>
```

When I click on the link google is loaded inside the app.

I am retireibving the posts data using WordPress Rest API.
For that I am using this:

```
getPosts: function() {

        var rootURL = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: rootURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    console.log(value.featured_image);
                  $('ul.homepost-list').append('<li class="homepost-list__item">' +
                    '<a href="'+value.link+'">'+
                    '<img width="100" height="75" src="'+value.fimg_url+'" alt="'+value.title.rendered+'"/>'+
                    '<h3>'+value.title.rendered+'</h3>' +
                    '<p>'+value.excerpt.rendered+'</p>'+
                    '</a>'+
                    '</li>');
                    ;
                });
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }

        });

    }
```

but the when click on posts it opens in the browser.
to open it inside the app I have to use the onclick function like this: `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com', '_self ', 'location=yes');">google.com</a>`

So I've changed like this:

```
getPosts: function() {

        var rootURL = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: rootURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    console.log(value.featured_image);
                  $('ul.homepost-list').append('<li class="homepost-list__item">' +
                    '<a href="#" onclick="'+window.open(''+value.link+'', '_self ', 'location=yes')+'">'+
                    '<img width="100" height="75" src="'+value.fimg_url+'" alt="'+value.title.rendered+'"/>'+
                    '<h3>'+value.title.rendered+'</h3>' +
                    '<p>'+value.excerpt.rendered+'</p>'+
                    '</a>'+
                    '</li>');
                    ;
                });
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }

        });

    }
```

But now the anchor onclick value is NULL [onclik null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgtDt.png)

I think this is because of this line has a syntex error`'<a href="#" onclick="'+window.open(''+value.link+'', '_self ', 'location=yes')+'">'+`

How do I have to change this syntax line to get it work?
It's just a simple syntax error I know but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work on how you add strings and variables as well as single and double quotes. See fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/designtocode/u3o57jr2/3/

```
onclick="'+window.open(''+value.link+'', '_self ', 'location=yes')+'">'+
```

Needs to be:

```
onclick="window.open(\''+value.link+'\', \'_self \', \'location=yes\')">
```

This means the `onclick` and `window.open` needs to pass as strings and `value.link` needs to be a variable. Since we are using single quotes to escape javascript code, we need to add `\` before the single quote if you need it as a string.

I hope this makes sense and will help you in future.

Comment: thank you so much. could you please remove my site link from the fiddle? you can use some other public site feeds. this will effect SEO. :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your single quotes

```
window.open(\'+value.link+'\'
```